# Как в Spring Boot удалить токен с истёкшим сроком годности?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, авторизация

Смотрела гайды по JWT в Spring Boot, в нескольких из них создают только один токен на UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. Я тоже создала один токен и его срок годности истёк через две недели.

SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
не очищает старый Bearer. Как мне теперь от него избавиться, чтобы выдать на это раз два токена - access и refresh?